# 'JavaPackage' object is not callable when doing "ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)"

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I currently have Spark spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7 and Kafka kafka_2.11-2.4.1.

I'm trying to connect to an Apache Broker to process the data that is stored in a topic.

I am running the following code:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-8_2.11:2.4.7 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext("local[2]", "testtopic")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 2)
```

and I am getting the following error

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    File
> "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py",
> line 61, in **init**
> self._jssc = jssc or self._initialize_context(self._sc, batchDuration)   File
> "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py",
> line 64, in _initialize_context
> self._ensure_initialized()   File "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/streaming/context.py",
> line 88, in _ensure_initialized
> SparkContext._active_spark_context, CloudPickleSerializer(), gw)   File
> "/home/bupry_dev/development/spark_home/spark-2.4.7-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/streaming/util.py",
> line 106, in **init**
> self.gateway.jvm.PythonDStream.registerSerializer(self) TypeError: 'JavaPackage' object is not callable

I have tried with several --jars and --packages, with different versions and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. In every post they say you have to match the pre-built version (which is 2.11) of Spark with you Kafka and that is what I'm doing.

Comment: Do you need Spark? You can consume from Kafka with plain python libraries

Comment: @OneCricketeer Yes, i need spark because I would like to process the raw data into a structured Spark DF and save it to HDFS

Comment: Okay, just saying you should be able to do the same with `faust` and Kafka Connect HDFS Sink. But if you want to use a Dataframe, you want `spark-sql-kafka-010` package, and you would use `SparkSession.read`, not a StreamingContext